# Wireshark is crashing on startup (WIth DOIP and UDS plugins)

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have installed the wireshark version 2.4.5 using the code compilation. I also have added the DOIP and UDS plugins from [this](https://github.com/tobras/wireshark_doip) link.

I did the below instructions:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

then I started using

```
wireshark
```

and then it crashed:

> void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "" under id 193
>
> void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "" under id 194
>
> Duplicate field detected in call to proto_register_field_array: doip.version is already registered
>
> ERROR:packet.c:2930:register_dissector_handle: assertion failed: (g_hash_table_lookup(registered_dissectors, name) == NULL)
> Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: How about without those plugins? Although this doesn't even seem like a programming question.

Comment: Without the plugins, it works fine.